# Will an iOS app developed using material design be rejected by App Store

Tags: ios, user-interface, app-store

We are developing an iOS app, which requires material design like Text input layout,Switch compact, date and time pickers, animation effect like ripple to be supported. Planning to use the library provided in the below link 
https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS

I would like to understand whether there will be any rejection from appstore if we use material design. Also any suggestion/guidelines to be  followed for material design on iOS will be helpful.

Comment: Why would you do something like that? The users will hate your app.

Comment: Customer requirement, also there are many apps which are now trying to use material design